# доступ к оригинальной версии сайта

Tags: python

Нужно сделать парсер imdb по списку топ фильмов. Но при переходе по ссылке https://www.imdb.com/chart/top название фильмов в кирриличной форме. Нужно получить список в оригинальной форме с сайта.

```
url = 'https://www.imdb.com/chart/top'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Скорее всего, сервер по вашему ip понимает из какой страны и, соответственно, как язык. А что, на самом сайте нет никакой кнопки смены языка? Если нет, то, возможно, у сайта есть регистрация с личным кабинетом и там задать язык. Если и этого нет, то используйте прокси нужной страны

Answer (score 3):

Указанный вами сайт подстраивается под заголовок `Accept-Language`. Другими словами вам достаточно добавить его со значением `en` и сайт начнет выдавать результаты на указанном языке.

Я не особо силен в питоне, но предполагаю, что заголовок добавляется примерно так (тут думаю уже сами разберетесь):

```
headers = {'Accept-Language': 'en'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Только я не уверен, что оригинальный заголовок - это всегда заголовок на английском :)